# When updating a Google Drive Drawings on desktop web app, does iOS version update automatically?

Tags: google-drive, google-drawings

I've done a markup in Google Drive Drawings on my computer in the browser.

I'm talking to someone on the phone while they are looking at the drawing on their iOS device, do the drawings live update, like a doc or spreadsheet?

The obvious answer here would be try it out yourself, but I've had a look at it seems to either be a) extremely slow to update (I haven't seen it update at all this way) OR b) it only updates 'sometimes' when you leave the drawing and re-enter it.

Has anyone had any experience with this or is it normally quicker and Google Drive is just being a bit slow at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Google moved the editing capabilities from the Drive app to Docs, Sheets and Slides apps. As there isn't a Drawing app there is no real-time time for Drawings in iOS. On the other hand, the new versions require iOS 7.

To see the last changes, close the drawing, refresh Google Drive and open the drawing again.

**References from the Drive and Docs Help**
[View and edit files offline on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/107975?hl=en)
[Upgrade to iOS 7 or higher to edit documents](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4624330?hl=en)